# DynamoDB - Restore dropped global table into new global table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I dropped a DynamoDB global table ( having PITR enabled) accidentally.

I have a backup of the global table generated by PITR before drop but when i try to restore the backup it restores as a non global table.

is there any way i can restore into global table directly because the table was not empty so i m unable to make it global again.

I know the option of restoring first into non-global table, take backup again into S3 and then restore it in a global table.

But this is lengthy process, required more downtime and resources, also in this case there is no advantage of using Dynamo PITR.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a workaround at least:

1. Restore your data to a (non-global) table. Unfortunately you cannot convert this to a global table as it has data in it, but you can effectively do so by...
2. Export the data from the table into S3 using Data Pipeline
3. Create a brand new empty table and make it global
4. Import the data into the empty table from S3 using Data Pipeline. This will replicate the data across all global instances using streams

Comment: this includes lot of downtime.

Comment: @AmanAggarwal I was actually curious about this as well did you happen to find any other solution to this?

Comment: @click i didn't get any solution for this till now.